# Unable to delete row from table which include PK

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

By accident I have placed two rows instead one in table which have primary key. Now I am unable to delete any of this rows.

I have tried to delete it by rightclick and message shown on image appeared.

The query looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM  table
WHERE App_(...) = 56
```

and it returns a timeout.

What can I do to reverse this changes?

Comment: Honestly, never use the row edittor GUI; it's awful and very flaky at best. Try actually writing the SQL Statement and execute it instead.

Comment: So you are saying the best way is to insert every change on database into transactions?

Comment: I'm saying write your SQL out, don't rely on the (sometimes) awful GUIs that SSMS provides. If you are using the GUIs, it's often far better to use the script button, so that you can run the Batch(es) in a Query Window and debug any problems you have far more easily.

Answer (score 0):

> In your table MainCompany is primarykey which you can not keep duplicate. so just change any value in any one row from 846 to any value like 900 and then it would works. Later you can delete which you don't wan't like with 900 value.

Comment: My primary key is first column. App_zgłoszenie

Comment: If the primary key is declared then it should be unique, which means your commit on row #2 never happened so the row doesn't exist to be deleted. Open a second window and do a select from the table, see if you get 1 result or 2

Comment: I get the result which is displayed on the picture above. The PK i column App_zgłoszenie, and it is unique, values 55 and 56. And it was added automatically

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not even insert into the table, after closing the UI you can do a quick check by using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE App_(...) = 56
```

Comment: No the values was inserted into column for sure

Comment: Then try to perform `DELETE FROM table WHERE App_(...) = 56`. If that doesn't work either, try to write a statement with all detail information example: `DELETE FROM table WHERE App_(...) = 56 AND Uri IS NULL AND Applicationid IS NULL`

Comment: As I said in my question I tried to perfom DELETE FROM table WHERE App_(...) = 56. Adding more parameters do not change anything.